# Injected script doesn't execute even with script tags "fixed" up

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iwebbrowser2

I am injecting a DIV and some SCRIPT into the DOM of a document loaded into my IWebBrowser2 control.  I was unable to then execute the scripts because when injected that way they're not "real" script tags.

I found the solution, or so I thought, in a different question here.  The coded provided (below) seems to work - it replaces all of the injected text  tags with real script elements created with calls to createElement().

```
<script>
    function nodeScriptReplace(node)
    {
        if (nodeScriptIs(node) === true)
        {
            alert("Fixing " + node.id);
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(nodeScriptClone(node), node);
        }
        else
        {
            var i = 0;
            var children = node.childNodes;
            while (i < children.length)
            {
                nodeScriptReplace(children[i++]);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
    function nodeScriptIs(node)
    {
        return node.tagName === 'SCRIPT';
    }
    function nodeScriptClone(node)
    {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.text = node.innerHTML;
        for (var i = node.attributes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            script.setAttribute(node.attributes[i].name, node.attributes[i].value);
        }
        return script;
    }
    function FixAllScripts()
    {
        nodeScriptReplace(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I've verified it does exactly that, but when I try to ExecuteScript() on that  via the IWebBrowser2 control, it doesn't work.  I've verified it -does- work if I move that script into the original page rather than the injected block.  But I need it to execute the injected block.

The injected block looks like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: white;">
...etc'
</table>
<br />

<script id="SayHi">
    function SayHi() {
        alert("Hi!");
        return 5;
    }
</script>
```

In my code that hosts the control I do the following:

```
        var el = mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("InsertionPoint");
        el.InnerHtml = toInsert + el.InnerHtml + "<BR/>";

        var bar = mainBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("FixAllScripts");
        var foo = mainBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("SayHi");
```

So I inject my HTML and run the "FixAllScripts" script in the original page that should fix up the "SayHi" script.

I've verified the  tags I've injected get detected and "fixed up" by reaplceChild.  And yet executing them does nothing.

The ultimate question is why I cannot execute a  tag that was created with createElement(), or if I should be able to, what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 4):

Injected scripts NEVER gets executed. This is by design. There is nothing you can do.

There are only two ways to inject javascript into a page:

1. Load it via HTTP. Yes, you can create a script tag with `createElement()` but it only works when you load the script from a file via HTTP using the `src` attribute. Manually changing the content of the script tag was long ago considered a security issue and no browser have ever allowed this since the original implementation of javascript on Netscape Navigator.
2. Use `eval()`. Yes eval is evil but it does allow you to do `eval(script.innerHTML)` to execute the content of a script tag. My advice is if you ever find yourself needing eval then it's time to re-evaluate what you're trying to do and reconsider your architecture.

Answer (score -2):

This judgment

```
if (nodeScriptIs(node) === true)
```

always returnd `false`.